# Antd Table onChange event not working when console.log is passed

Tags: reactjs, antd

When console.log is passed as the event handler to onChange of table, the event is not fired.

```
<Table
    rowKey={(record) => record.id}
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={getData(page)}
    pagination={{ current: page, total: 100, pageSize: 20 }}
    onChange={console.log}
  />
```

But the event fires when a function that console.log's is passed as the argument.

```
<Table
    rowKey={(record) => record.id}
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={getData(page)}
    pagination={{ current: page, total: 100, pageSize: 20 }}
    onChange={(...args) => console.log(...args)}
  />
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-wescoff-fzm4y?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `onChange={console.log}`, you are pointing to `disabledLog` from React.
When `onChange()` is called, event React has `reenableLogs()` but you still point the `disabledLog`, which will log nothing to console.

When passing `(...args) => console.log(...args)`, you has create a closure point to `console`.

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/HEAD/packages/shared/ConsolePatchingDev.js

Answer (score -1):

`console.log` is a function, so to call it you must add `()` and give it arguments as we do for other functions.